# json string formatting integer values

Tags: json

I'm trying to understand a simple basic concept regarding JSON strings.  I'm running a simple test that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var last = 9;
 var json1 = $.parseJSON('{"id":"10"}');
 var json2 = $.parseJSON('{"id":10}');

 if(json1.id > last)
    alert("json1.id is greater than last");

 if(json2.id > last)
    alert("json2.id is greater than last");

});
```

Since the variable "last" is type int I'm trying to make a comparison between it and the "id" from two different JSON strings.  json1 denotes the ten value as a string, whereas json2 denotes it as an integer value.  When this is run, both alerts are executed.  I did not expect that. I expected that the second alert would execute, but not the first one since ten is presented as a string.

I believe that the correct way to format an integer value in JSON is in json2, right?

Why is the first test executing the alert?

I'm trying to troubleshoot a larger project and thought the problem might be in the way the JSON string is formatted.

Comment: It's Javascript, it doesn't really care about types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of Javascript's operators holds all the answers:

> Strings are compared based on standard lexicographical ordering, using
>   Unicode values. In most cases, if the two operands are not of the same
>   type, JavaScript attempts to convert them to an appropriate type for
>   the comparison. This behavior generally results in comparing the
>   operands numerically. The sole exceptions to type conversion within
>   comparisons involve the === and !== operators, which perform strict
>   equality and inequality comparisons. These operators do not attempt to
>   convert the operands to compatible types before checking equality.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators